How can i use the azure-cost accumulatedCost tool with Azure and no mfa user?
I am running something like the following to get some costs in Azure
az login --service-principal --username <clientid> --password <pwd> -- 
tenant <tenantid>
az account set --subscription <test_subscription>

azure-cost accumulatedCost -s 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

But this gives an error that it cant find my subscription that i set, ie test_subscription
So i did what the error suggested
   az login --service-principal -u <clientid> -p <clientsecret> --tenant <tenantid>

It still gives the error that test_subscription doesnt exist.
I used to use
   az login -u johndoe@contoso.com -p VerySecret
   az account set --subscription "test_subscription"

But because johndoe@contoso.com  uses mfa , it says that it wont work .
How can i fix this ?

Are you providing the right subscription name? @Fiona

See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/troubleshoot-subscription/troubleshoot-sign-in-issue

Need to check below:
Execute az account list CLI command and verify the logged in accounts as shown below. Check if the providing test_subscription has existed in the retrieved accounts list.

Try clearing all the logged in accounts in the current console environment with az account clear command and relog in with the az login command.
Once logged in, check the subscription details along with the username with az account show command.
Instead of passing a subscription name <test_subscription>, try providing the subscription Id as shown in the below way.
az account set --subscription "Subscription_ID"
Also verify whether the subscription has existed under the specific tenant directory by passing a search phase query as given below. If found, then try setting the subscription again with the above command.
az account list --query "[?contains(name,'JAHNAVI')].{SubscriptionName:name, SubscriptionID:id, TenantID:tenantId}" --output table


Refer multiple subscriptions management in Azure CLI.
If still the issue persists, try logging in with the managed identity.

